# Underbrace with boisik

Tags: fonts, math-fonts, underbrace

Is there a way of making underbrace work with boisik? Here is a minimal non-working example:

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{boisik}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\[
\underbrace{xx}_{xx}
\]
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this (I use pdfLaTeX as a compiler):

[image]

Comment: As far as I see, boisk doesn't support these "characters" https://markov.htwsaar.de/tex-archive/fonts/boisik/example/table.pdf . At least it's not clear to what extent it supports math mode. // Perhaps you need to switch to a different font for those lines of code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get

```
Missing character: There is no z in font bskex10!
Missing character: There is no | in font bskex10!
Missing character: There is no { in font bskex10!
Missing character: There is no z in font bskex10!
Missing character: There is no } in font bskex10!
```

You can recover the missing glyphs by importing the standard ones.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{boisik}

\DeclareSymbolFont{cmlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\braceld}{\mathord}{cmlargesymbols}{"7A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bracerd}{\mathord}{cmlargesymbols}{"7B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bracelu}{\mathord}{cmlargesymbols}{"7C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\braceru}{\mathord}{cmlargesymbols}{"7D}

\begin{document}
\[
\underbrace{xxxxxxxx}_{xx} \quad \overbrace{xxxxxxxx}^{xx}
\]
\end{document}
```

You have to realize that `boisik` is only available in bitmap format, though…

[image]